# Coding method: storing methods as object properties

Tags: javascript, json, tiles

While reading [Hashrocket's blog](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/using-tiled-and-canvas-to-render-game-screens) on tilemapping, I learned about a new way of organizing code.

The way I'm used to is:

```
(function start () {
   scene();
})();

function scene() {
   renderLayer();
}

function renderLayer() {
   var x
   var y
}
```

etc...

Hashrocket creates an object within a function wrapper and adds functions and variables as attributes to the object:

```
$(function() {
    var scene = {
      layers: [],
      renderLayer: function(layer) { },
      renderLayers: function(layers) { },
      loadTileset: function(json) { },
      load: function(name) { }
    }

scene.load(something);

});
```

What is the name and what are the differences/benefits of this style of coding? It seems OOP-like, as `scene = {` would be the class, and its properties would be the methods/attr within the class.

Thanks!

Comment: OOP typically comes with inheritance, this module doesn't...

Comment: Well you're right: This way of organizing your code is a way of writing OOP. A big bennefit by using it this way is to keep the global scope tidy! So that you will have less problems with different Bundles! Probably if you go on reading the blog you'll learn how to add inheritance to Objects or how to inherit from other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of storing your functions in an object is reducing the odds of a name clash. Your first example pollutes the global namespace with `scene()` and `renderLayer()` which is potentially dangerous if you have a moderate code base that includes other packages and modules.

In the second snippet, `scene` is defined inside a anonymous function. This provides two benefits:

- It makes the `scene` object inaccessible to code outside the function. [Information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) is enforced.
- The evaluation of the declarations is deferred until the page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.). This guarantees all resources will be available.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, enclosing all your code within the anonymous function is better practice, since you're not polluting the namespace with functions. For another, the second example is better organized, since you know exactly what data/functions belong together.

It's not OOP, however, since you're not creating new instances of Scene.

Answer (score 1):

Former example is an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) whereas latter one is just wrapping all the code(methods and state of object) that should belong together in the given JS object.